# Facing issue in having clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, having

```
select *
from db_user
order by date_created asc OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
having full_name like 'Admin%';
```

Getting Error:

> [S0001][156] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'having'.

How to resolve this issue because 'where' clause also giving error.

Comment: `having` is for use with a `group by` - you want a `where` clause, and it goes *before* the `order by`

Comment: @DaleK Your answer help me run the query but i am still unable to achieve the required result.

Comment: Given we can't see your sample data or expected result, there isn't much help we can provide.

Comment: @DaleK updated the question please check now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`having` is used to filter out grouped results from a `group by` clause. If you just want to filter out rows, you should use a `where` clause. Note that it should come **before** the `order by` clause:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     db_user
WHERE    full_name LIKE'Admin%' -- Here!
ORDER BY date_created ASC OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 1):

**HAVING** is used in queries with a groupby statement to filter results based on the values of *aggregated columns*. You should use **WHERE** instead.

The right query reads:

```
select *
from db_user
where full_name like 'Admin%'
order by date_created asc OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
;
```